# How do I remove the grey area that develops at the end of a View when I specify a borderRadius on react-native running on Iphone 6+?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am writing a View on react-native expo, I want one of the Views to have a borderRadius on all platforms and handsets

I tested the app on Android, and it works on all Android phones I have tested with. With iOs, I tested on the iPhone 8 and it works just fine. On the iPhone 6+ it develops a grey area. When i remove the borderRadius it is fine on all platforms

This is my view

```
<View style={styles.meterInputView}>
   <Image onTouchEndCapture={() => this.setState({ error: true })} source={require('../assets/error.png')} style={{ display: this.state.meterField, width: 16, height: 16, margin: 7, display: this.state.invalidMeter }}> 
   </Image>
    {this.renderCamera()}
    <TextInput style={styles.meterInput} ref={comp => { this.textInputRef = comp; }} name={'meter_input'} keyboardType={'phone-pad'} placeholder={'Type/Scan Meter Number'} value={this.state.meter} onChangeText={(meter) => this.validateOnType(meter)}></TextInput>
 </View>
```

This is my Style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    meterInputView: {
        overflow: 'hidden',
        width: '70%',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 5,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: '#95989A',
        height: 30,
        marginLeft: '10%',
        marginTop: '4%',
        flex: 2,
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
```

I expect that when I specify the borderRadius the View remain cosnistent in all platform handsets but instead a grey area develops on the iPhone 6+ at the end of the View

Comment: You mean all but the iPhone 8 have gray areas?

Comment: iPhone 8 is fine, all the iphone 6+ have grey areas

Comment: It seems to be an area problem according to screen size. I think we need to separate the areas according to the device.

Comment: @hongdevelop how do we do that?

Comment: Use the model name of 'Constants.platform.ios.model' to separate and style.

Comment: Alright thanks but how do I style for the iphone 6+? So it has a borderRadius without developing the grey area

Comment: If you are using iPhone 6+, try increasing the height value.